# Ultimate chars to escape list for php, javascript and mysql

Tags: javascript, php, string, security, escaping

Many sites uses php and javascript and mysql. I'd like to know the chars to escape, when and how, for the site security(not paranoid but good security)(and performance).
This is what I do now:
When saving user submited string:

```
//I set the utf8 charset everywhere
$str = urldecode($str);
$str = trim($_POST['name']);
if (mb_strlen($str, 'utf-8') <= $maxsize) //{...
//remove tab, null, backspace, controlz chars
$str = str_replace(array("\t","\x00","\x08","\x1a"),"",$str);
$str = str_replace(["%","_"],["\%","\_"],$str); // if I use like in the query
//I use prepared statement to insert in db, so i dont need to escape quotes and others
$stmt = $sql->prepare("INSERT INTO atable (acol) VALUES (?)");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $str);
$stmt->execute();
```

Now when displaying a string from the db, with php echo, that could also be  javascript code and vars. I replace with entities these: <>&'"`\$%{}[]_; .

```
$a = array("<",">","&","'",'"',"\\","$","%","_","{","}","[","]",";");
$b = array("&lt;","&gt;","&#38;","&#39;","&#34;","&#92;","&#36;","&#37;","&#95;","&#123;","&#125;","&#91;","&#93;","&#59;");
$str = str_replace($a,$b,$str);
echo $str;
```

Anything wrong? Missing or unnecessary chars ?

**Updates**
The left/right single/double quotation mark (like [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_charset.asp) calls em) can be dangerous ???

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. Don't try to have one universal function. Use something prewritten that is sensible for the context you are using the data in.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is flawed right out of the gate.

**Don't try to solve all of your security needs with a one-size-fits-all function.**

Security considerations are domain-specific. Protecting against SQL injection requires a different strategy than defending against cross-site scripting, XPath injection, LDAP injection, etc..

[Start with a threat model](https://adamcaudill.com/2016/07/20/threat-modeling-for-applications/). Without fully understanding the problems you want to solve, you won't be able to create adequate solutions to them. A lot of problem have known solutions.

- SQL injection (SQLi) is best [prevented through the correct use of prepared statements](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/preventing-sql-injection-in-php-applications-easy-and-definitive-guide)
- Cross-site scripting (XSS) is best [prevented through escaping on output, not on input](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/06/preventing-xss-vulnerabilities-in-php-everything-you-need-know)

If you don't feel comfortable enumerating the vulnerabilities you're concerned about, it may be helpful to read [the Security section of *PHP: The Right Way*](https://phptherightway.com/#security).